# Jersey Resource Filters

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

Jersey allows [resource filters](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.2/jersey/com/sun/jersey/spi/container/ResourceFilter.html) applied to resource classes, resource methods, sub-resource methods or sub-resource locators.

When applied to a sub-resource locator: is the response filter applied before or after the processing of the returned subresource?

Answer (score 1):

The filter applied before the processing of the returned subresource.